# Web service request times out after app pool recycles

Tags: web-services, iis

I have a classic web service that is hosted on IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2).
After application pool recycles (default 20 minutes idle state), the first request to the web service takes about 5 minutes. When it gets through, every other request to the service takes no time at all.

I read about turning on AlwaysRunning in the IIS 7.5 that is in applicationHost.config. However, I would appreciate if anybody can provide explanation why would it happen and where to search for the cause of the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid a cold start by having a heartbeat execute prior to the app pool recycle interval. However, you still need to let the app pools recycle at some pre-determined interval. See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97538/why-after-each-restart-my-local-net-sites-take-time-to-load-for-the-first-time) post on cold starts. Generally, the more dependencies your app consumes and the larger your code base is then the longer it will take to "wake up" on a cold start. The delay is not really noticeable for smaller apps.